# How to get number of throughputs per second as 500 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Good day.

I am new to J-Meter and here is the requirement I need to verify through J-meter TP.
I am using Jmeter: 5.1 version.

1. I need to get the results for 500 throughput per seconds.
2. Number of target users : 100
3. Time to run the test 1 hr.
4. Start the test with 5 users and increase the load by setting every 3 seconds 5 more users up to add till we reach reaching 100 users.
5. Once we reach 100 users >> Keep the load for 10 seconds hold and decrease the load by every 3 seconds to reduce 5 number of usrs.

Please help me on what are the parameters I have to set in J-Meter test plan.

Thanks.
Siva

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of controlling the number of requests per second (throughput) in JMeter test is using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/)

1. Add Constant Throughput Timer to your Test plan and configure it to send `30000` requests per minute (500 requests per second)
2. Make sure that all the Samplers are in the Constant Throughput Timer's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) and you have `all active threads` selected in the dropdown

   [image]
3. You can only achieve 500 requests per second with 100 users if your application response time is 200 ms or less, if it's more - you will have to increase the number of threads accordingly.
4. And last but not the least, [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMete](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)r (5.3 as of now) so consider upgrading at next available opportunity

Answer (score 0):

Below are some suggestions that might help you to start with:

1. You might need to calculate the pacing required to achieve target total transactions:

   Pacing = 3600(Test duration time in seconds) * ( target no.of user) / (no.of total transactions to achieve).
2. To setup ramp up, ramp down more effectively you will need one of the plugin available in Jmeter Plugins Manager (Plugin name : Stepping Thread Group by blazemeter) which comes with a preview.
3. How to setup Plugins manager (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)